# how it is to create a category, subcatagory, subsub category on phpmyadmin

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I want to build a database website to practice.

It is a travel guide website. In the main page have a menu with home, continent, tips, routes, contact us. The menus have a dropdown submenus with Europe, Asia and North America (for continent); things to do, where to go, restaurants and hotels (for tips); where to go and things to do (for routes). Each submenu opens to another page with a dynamic gallery (where I could add or erase new items dynamically) only showing the photo and a name. When I click on the photo it opens another page with all information and more photos about the subject. And there the administration area with email, password.

**My question is:** how do I translate that to the PHPMyAdmin? I create a database and a table for

1. administration(with id, name and password),
2. Continent (with id, Europe, Asia, North America),
3. Europe(id, continent, state, city, photo, description),
4. Asia(id, continent, state, city, photo, description),
5. North America(id, continent, state, city, photo, description),
6. tips (id, activity, places to go, restaurant and hotels)
7. activiy (id, tips, location, what activity is, description, photos),
8. places to go(id, tips, location, what place is, description, photos),
9. restaurants(id, tips, location, what restaurant is, description, photos),
10. hotels(id, tips, location, what hotel is, description, photos),
11. routes(id, where to go and what to do),
12. where to go(id, route, location, description),
13. things to do(id, route, location, description).

Is that it? I have to create 13 tables exactly this way? Or is not necessary?

Comment: You don’t need a table for each category. Instead you could have one table for all of your content and add a ‘category ID’ or similar column. By the way, you might want to read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), since your post ended up… kind of mashed together in a single wall of text.

Comment: But I'll need to put all content (the menu and the submenu content), right? If so how it will know what information I'm calling when I click on a submenu to open a link?

Comment: You’d put some sort of identifying information in the URL. Maybe you’d have `category.php?cat_id=5`, for example. Your script would pull the `cat_id` out of `$_GET` and use that to fetch all relevant articles or subcategories or what-have-you. (And you’re not fixed to that URL format either; you could of course use your web server’s rewrite feature or something… again, possibilities are endless.)